# require_once not executing php code wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm developing a plugin, but there is something wrong with my `require_once`.
I'm requiring a file like so:

```php
<?php require_once plugin_dir_path( __DIR__ ) . "Form/new_form.php" ?>
```

the new form is visible on the page, but if I want to add php in new_form.php that will not parse. It will display the php code as text but I don't know how to fix.

```html
<img id="klantlogo" src="<?php get_option('form_klantlogo_url') //this is from browser inspect element ?>" />
```

please help

Comment: Try `echo get_option(...`

Comment: no that did not work, my php code will not run in that entire file

Comment: Show some more context … is `<img id="klantlogo"` part of a string variable value already maybe? Then you need to use string concatenation, not an additional “nested” PHP block with an echo.

Comment: what do you mean by "new_form.php that will not parse"? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: i'm loading my login page in my settings page so u can see realtime what is changing. the login form is showing up, but if i use php code in my loginform file, it will not run that code

Comment: I tried to echo the entire image tag in php like this: `<?php echo "<img id='klantlogo' src='" . get_option('form_klantlogo_url') . "' /> " ?>`  but that will not help as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did fix this problem. I was a little bit unclear what i meant, but i fixed it with this code:

```
global $wp;
//check if login page
if( '/login/' === add_query_arg( $wp->query_vars ) ) { 
    //remove standard wordpress login form
    wp_enqueue_script('remove_form',  plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . '/Form/remove_login_form.js', null, null, true);

    //require a custom html template for login form
    require __DIR__ . '/Form/new_form.php';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd check your error_log. I'm betting you have php errors - like not ending that php line of code with a semi colon;

If you post the code from new_form.php we can help you.

Comment: I found my problem. But i don't know how to fix. I pass file_get_contents of my login page in my js file to load the new template. Is there any wp hook for loading another template on page load?

Comment: You have two options I know of:  add_filter( 'page_template', array( $this, 'add_page_template'), 10, 3 ); or you can load the template with jQuery and populate the variables after.